OpenReWrite Problem with NoAutowiredOnConstructor
I am tryin to move from Spring 2.7 to Spring 3 using OpenRewrite. The first step I tried is the Spring 3 migration. The recipe NoAutowiredOnConstructor is causing a problem. As I understand it, it looks for @Autowired in a single constructor and removes if present. It also removes the import of "Autowired" which is calling the problem. A lot of out code has empty constructors and uses @Autowired for field injection. I know the arguments that we should use constructor injection...but there is a lot of code setup like this and I would prefer not to take on those changes as part of the migration. The recipe sees the constructor (without Autowired) and then removes the Autowired import. The result is the processed code does not compile.
Is there a way to address this issue in the existing recipe or can I disable the recipe as part of the Spring 3 recipe?
Thanks in advance,

hi! It's not immediately clear to me what type of failure you're seeing based on the above. Could you report this as a failing unit test perhaps? See this class for examples
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/blob/624df943a224a2cc6a63c79e9716ece55197c88b/src/testWithSpringBoot_1_5/java/org/openrewrite/java/spring/NoAutowiredOnConstructorTest.java#L27
